# Selecting element(s) from a list in Python

Tags: python, string

Trying to get user input, find the index of those elements in the "alphabet" variable, store them, find the elements of the same index in the "key" variable, and print them out. Here is what I have so far, but cannot get the elements from the "key" variable to print...

```
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
plain = input("Type something: ").upper()
result = [alphabet.index(i) for i in plain]
print (result)
coded = [result.?(i) for i in key]
print (coded)
```

Comment: It isn't a method.  Use `result[i]`.  Okay, technically it's just a shortcut for `result.__getitem__(i)`, but anyway...

Comment: You have 3 solutions, 0, votes, 0 accepted answers, and 0 comments. Do any of them work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the indices (in your `result` list) it is simply a matter to print out the elements at the same indices of `key` list. You should simply write this line

```
coded = [result.?(i) for i in key]
```

as

```
coded = [key[i] for i in result]
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much! What is the difference in between using parenthesis and square brackets in the "i for i" functions?

Comment: Square brackets are used for list indexing (in this case) while parentheses are used for other things, such as method arguments, tuple creation etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood the question correctly, but if I did, then this code would work

```
key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
plain = input("Type something: ").upper()
result = []
for letter in plain:
    if letter in alphabet: result.append(letter)
print (result)
coded = []
for i in range(len(result)):
    if result[i] == key[i]: coded.append(result[i])
print (coded)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). It's used to create a function which will get one or more items by index from its argument.

```
from operator import itemgetter

key =   "XPMGTDHLYONZBWEARKJUFSCIQV"
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
plain = input("Type something: ").upper()
result = [alphabet.index(i) for i in plain]
print (result)
coded = itemgetter(*result)(key)  # Returns a tuple
# coded = ''.join(coded)          # Make a string from the tuple
print (coded)
```